# How to select a value if multiple records can be found on the same date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, subquery

Can somebody advise me to improve this subquery to be able to get only a single record based on the following calculations, the subquery below this post brings the following result:

```
PERCENT ¦ LOG_DATE ¦ APP ¦ REQ_ID
55 ¦ 2017-02-07 15:44:22 ¦ HUO ¦ 253333
63 ¦ 2017-02-08 10:42:18 ¦ CQS ¦ 265265
75 ¦ 2017-02-08 06:55:12 ¦ CQS ¦ 265265
84 ¦ 2017-02-09 08:35:42 ¦ CQS ¦ 265265
40 ¦ 2017-02-09 09:45:14 ¦ PLK ¦ 277777
```

I would like to see only those records within the result, which having the newest date (al.AU_TIME) per date. The goal would be to work toward with the record which has the percent value of '63'. Query should bring:

```
55 ¦ 2017-02-07 15:44:22 ¦ HUO ¦ 253333
63 ¦ 2017-02-08 10:42:18 ¦ CQS ¦ 265265
84 ¦ 2017-02-09 08:35:42 ¦ CQS ¦ 265265
40 ¦ 2017-02-09 09:45:14 ¦ PLK ¦ 277777
```

So how should I do it if multiple records having the same REQ_ID on a same day.

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(RTRIM(ap.AP_NEW_VALUE,'%')) as PERCENT,
   al.AU_TIME as LOG_DATE,
   req.RQ_USER_03 as APP,
   req.RQ_REQ_ID as REQ_ID
FROM AUDIT_PROPERTIES ap,
     AUDIT_LOG al,
     REQ
WHERE al.AU_ACTION_ID = ap.AP_ACTION_ID and
      req.RQ_REQ_ID = al.AU_ENTITY_ID and
      req.rq_req_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('05/02/2017','dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('20/02/2017','dd/mm/yyyy') and
      ap.AP_FIELD_NAME = 'RQ_USER_58'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have "a table".  Your sample code has *three* tables.  What is your real question?

Comment: Sorry for my poor english, edited above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in a single aggregate query (no subqueries). Group by `req_id` and by `trunc(log_date)`, then select just one record per group. `req_id` and `max(log_date)` (**within** each group, that is within each day) are obvious. Then use the `first/last` function (`keep (dense_rank...)`. You need to take just a little bit of care if it is possible to have two rows with exactly the same date **and time** (down to the second) for a given `req_id`.

Here's one way to do it. I put the test data you supplied in a `WITH` clause for testing and illustration purposes, but that is **not** part of the query.

```
with
     test_data ( percent, log_date, app, req_id ) as (
       select 55, to_date('2017-02-07 15:44:22', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'HUO', 253333
       from dual union all
       select 63, to_date('2017-02-08 10:42:18', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'CQS', 265265
       from dual union all
       select 75, to_date('2017-02-08 06:55:12', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'CQS', 265265
       from dual union all
       select 84, to_date('2017-02-09 08:35:42', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'CQS', 265265
       from dual union all
       select 40, to_date('2017-02-09 09:45:14', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'PLK', 277777
       from dual
     )
--  End of test data (not part of the solution). SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select max(percent) keep (dense_rank last order by log_date)          as percent,
       max(log_date)                                                  as log_date,
       max(app)     keep (dense_rank last order by log_date, percent) as app,
       req_id
from   test_data
group by req_id, trunc(log_date)
order by log_date, req_id
;

PERCENT LOG_DATE   APP  REQ_ID
------- ---------- --- -------
     55 2017-02-07 HUO  253333
     63 2017-02-08 CQS  265265
     84 2017-02-09 CQS  265265
     40 2017-02-09 PLK  277777

4 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical way of doing this uses `row_number()`.  Best as I can guess in your case:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by req_id order by log_date desc) as seqnum
      from atable a
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: *per date* in the narrative, as well as the provided test data and desired result, suggest that the OP wanted `trunc(log_date)` to be part of `partition by` along with `req_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing an inner query or creating an intermediate table that groups the data by just date and calculates the max_time for each date
The Inner query would look like this:

```
SELECT cast(al.AU_TIME as date) as LOG_DATE,
max(al.AU_TIME) as max_LOG_TIME
FROM AUDIT_PROPERTIES ap,
     AUDIT_LOG al,
     REQ
WHERE al.AU_ACTION_ID = ap.AP_ACTION_ID and
      req.RQ_REQ_ID = al.AU_ENTITY_ID and
      req.rq_req_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('05/02/2017','dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('20/02/2017','dd/mm/yyyy') and
      ap.AP_FIELD_NAME = 'RQ_USER_58'
GROUP BY LOG_DATE
```

Then the outer query needs to be joined with this inner query on the timestamp value to get just those records

```
Select TO_NUMBER(RTRIM(ap.AP_NEW_VALUE,'%')) as PERCENT,
        al.AU_TIME,
        req.RQ_USER_03 as APP,
   req.RQ_REQ_ID as REQ_ID
   FROM AUDIT_PROPERTIES ap
   inner join (
SELECT cast(al.AU_TIME as date) as LOG_DATE,
max(al.AU_TIME) as max_LOG_TIME
FROM AUDIT_PROPERTIES ap,
     AUDIT_LOG al,
     REQ
WHERE al.AU_ACTION_ID = ap.AP_ACTION_ID and
      req.RQ_REQ_ID = al.AU_ENTITY_ID and
      req.rq_req_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('05/02/2017','dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('20/02/2017','dd/mm/yyyy') and
      ap.AP_FIELD_NAME = 'RQ_USER_58'
GROUP BY LOG_DATE) 
AS X
ON ap.AU_TIME= X.max_LOG_TIME
INNER JOIN AUDIT_LOG al
on al.AU_ACTION_ID = ap.AP_ACTION_ID
INNER JOIN REQ
ON req.RQ_REQ_ID = al.AU_ENTITY_ID
WHERE req.rq_req_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('05/02/2017','dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('20/02/2017','dd/mm/yyyy') and
      ap.AP_FIELD_NAME = 'RQ_USER_58'
```